# Running Tensorflow frozen_graph through opencv fail with dim denoted by -1 in function 'computeShapeByReshapeMask'

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I am make an AI that have to differentiate one bottle form from any other forms
and run the prediction through opencv

the learning (running the learning file) go very well but when I try to run the prediction with openCV I always get the same error

What am I doing wrong?

The error when launching the prediction file

```
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3441) getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: [Reshape]:(sequential/flatten/Reshape): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=1 outputs=1/0 blobs=0
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3447) getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 1 480 640 ]
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3451) getLayerShapesRecursively     output[0] = [ 1 921600 ]
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3457) getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/reshape_layer.cpp:154: error: (-1:Backtrace) Can't infer a dim denoted by -1 in function 'computeShapeByReshapeMask'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    bottle.process()
  File "main.py", line 28, in process
    networkOutput = self.net.forward()
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/reshape_layer.cpp:154: error: (-1:Backtrace) Can't infer a dim denoted by -1 in function 'computeShapeByReshapeMask'
```

Learning file

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import pathlib

from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

print(tf.__version__)

data_dir = pathlib.Path(
    "./data/training" #Base folder
)

frozen_out_path = 'frozen'
frozen_graph_filename = "frozen_graph"

img_height = 480
img_width = 640
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1/255)

num_classes = len(train_ds.class_names)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)



model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(
    normalization_layer
)
model.add(
    layers.Flatten()
)
model.add(
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='relu')
)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)


model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=3
)

model.save('output')

model.summary()

'''
    EXPORTING
'''
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype)
)

frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()

layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]

tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir=frozen_out_path,
                  name=f"{frozen_graph_filename}.pb",
                  as_text=False)
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir=frozen_out_path,
                  name=f"{frozen_graph_filename}.pbtxt",
                  as_text=True)
```

Prediction file

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

MODULEPREFIX = "../IA/frozen/"

class BottleDetector:

    def __init__(self):
        self.net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODULEPREFIX + 'frozen_graph.pb')
        self.net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT)
        self.net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

        self.classnames = ['Autre', 'Kerea']

    def process(self):
        inimggray = cv2.imread('./input.jpg')
        inimggray = cv2.cvtColor(inimggray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        inimggray = cv2.resize(inimggray, (640, 480))

        # Detect edges using the Canny algorithm from OpenCV:
        edges = cv2.Canny(inimggray, 100, 150, L2gradient = True)

        cv2.imwrite('./img.png', edges)
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(inimggray, 1 / 255.0, (640, 480), swapRB=False, crop=True)

        self.net.setInput(blob)

        networkOutput = self.net.forward()

        for detection in networkOutput[0,0]:
            print(detection[2])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle = BottleDetector()
    bottle.process()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my TensorFlow model, and was able to solve it through the following post:

[How to convert PyTorch graph to ONNX and then inference from OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587336/how-to-convert-pytorch-graph-to-onnx-and-then-inference-from-opencv)

In function `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage()`, I changed the `size` parameter to the same image size used to train my CNN. This eliminated the error message for me.

The images I used to test the training code for the TensorFlow CNN were retrieved from the same video collection I'm using to test the OpenCV code for object recognition.